# How to run a workflow using github cli?

Tags: github, github-cli

```
% gh workflow run test.yml
```

gives me:

```
could not create workflow dispatch event: HTTP 422: Workflow does not have 'workflow_dispatch' trigger (https://api.github.com/repos/bcpitutor/v2_lms/actions/workflows/20724896/dispatches)
```

Why do I need a workflow_dispatch trigger?

Comment: This is the way to allow the workflow to be run manually: ["To run a workflow manually, the workflow must be configured to run on the `workflow_dispatch` event."](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow)

Answer (score 1):

The [`gh workflow run`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) man page does confirm:

> The given workflow file **must support a `workflow_dispatch 'on'` trigger** in order to be run in this way.

It comes from [`cli/cli` issue 1725](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1725), and [issue 2889](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2889), implemented by [PR 3303](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/3303).

> This PR implements gh workflow run, a command for creating `workflow_dispatch` events for workflows that support them

Again, a confirmation your workflow needs to support that `workflow_dispatch` trigger.